# Как смапить Hibernate?

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate, java, tomcat, mysql

Пытаюсь модифицировать [petclinic](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html). Создано 3 таблицы в БД. Это

- `Lessons(id,name,teacher,description)`
- `Students(id,first_name,last_name,birthday,faculty)`
- `Group(id_student,id_lesson)`

Вот кусок **.hbm.xml

```
<class name="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Students" table="students">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="first_name" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
    <property name="last_name" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
    <property name="birthday" type="java.util.Date" column="birthday" />
    <property name="faculty" type="int" />
    <set name="lessonsInternal" table="group">
        <key column="student_id" />
        <many-to-many column="lesson_id" class="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Lessons" />
    </set>
</class>
<class name="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Lessons" table="lessons">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
    <property name="teacher" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
    <property name="description" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

Бины:

```
public class BaseEntity {

    private Integer id;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        return (this.id == null);
    }

}

package org.springframework.samples.petclinic;

import java.util.Date;

public class Students extends BaseEntity {
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private Date birthday;
    private int faculty;
    private boolean changed;

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public int getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }

    public void setFaculty(int facult) {
        this.faculty = facult;
    }

    public boolean isChanged() {
        return changed;
    }

    public void setChanged(boolean changed) {
        this.changed = changed;
    }

}

package org.springframework.samples.petclinic;

public class Lessons extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private String teacher;
    private String description;
    private boolean changed;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isChanged() {
        return changed;
    }

    public void setChanged(boolean changed) {
        this.changed = changed;
    }
}
```

**Ну и собственно сама ошибка:**

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for lessonsInternal in class org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Students
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:78)
    ... 38 more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтото подсказывает, что ошибка в xml в плане правильности имени переменной...

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for lessonsInternal in class org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Students
```

Comment: Благодарен!!

Comment: да не зачто, это предположение, с явой знаком на поверхностном уровне, ошибки у них конечно вылезают неудобными для анализа...